# Pedir permissão para acessar o armazenamento interno do Android por uma Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

Como faço para **pedir permissão para acessar o armazenamento interno** do aparelho por uma Fragment?

Na **activity normal** eu usei esse código:

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] 
{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A classe `Fragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)` tem um método `requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)`

Exemplo:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
        requestPermissions(new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);

    }


    // Sobrescrever método para receber resultado das permissões
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    }
```

Caso você queira checar uma permissão no `Fragment`, você pode utilizar:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE
            );
        } else {
            // permissão concedida
        }
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353688/4181975